# Controller in module not defined

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am just new using angular. And this time I am working on with a login form by using free open source codes from github named [Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic](https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic)

In the app.js, there defines some controllers that is used for the login app.

```
angular.module('AuthenticateMe', [
  'ionic',
  'controllers.main',
  'controllers.auth',
  'controllers.profile',
  'controllers.users',
  'controllers.users.profile',
  'services.common.constants',
  'services.common.auth',
  'components.http-auth-interceptor',
  'ngCordova.plugins.network'
])
```

Everything works fine there.

However, when I defined new controller there, the app is only blank.

```
angular.module('AuthenticateMe', [
  'ionic',
  'controllers.main',
  'controllers.auth',
  'controllers.profile',
  'controllers.users',
  'controllers.mynewcontrollerhere', //This is my new controller
  'controllers.users.profile',
  'services.common.constants',
  'services.common.auth',
  'components.http-auth-interceptor',
  'ngCordova.plugins.network'
])
```

This is the mynewcontroller

```
  angular.module('controllers.mynewcontroller', ['ngCordova.plugins.camera'])

  .controller('MynewCtrl', [
    '$cordovaCamera',
    '$ionicActionSheet',
    '$ionicModal',
    '$ionicLoading',
    '$ionicPopup',
    '$timeout',
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    '$stateParams',
    'Constants',
    'AuthService',
```

Note: I put the new controller in the new directory **controllers/mynewcontroller/main.js** (the main.js is the name of the new controller)

The question is, why does my controller can't be access and make the app doesn't work?

Please, anybody helps. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What error happens?

Comment: Your comment "this is my new controller" should rather be "this is my new module"

Comment: You also need to include file with your controller before app.js script

Comment: I can't see the error message because I only able to test it from the phonegap device app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have included your script in the main app, in order to have access to controller you need to include it in your template/html file.

Regarding how you should include the controller in your template...if you declared the controller as `MynewCtrl`, then in your template you should define the controller as:

```
<div ng-controller="MynewCtrl">
    <!-- body here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank, I forgot about it. So there would be many script is loaded in the app?

Comment: Based on your edit, it seems that I can include the controller in a specify template only? No need to also put it in the index.html?

Comment: You have to include the `.js` file, and no other action is needed, above the ones i specified.